# Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/pdf" pythonanywhere server log

Tags: python, html, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to Use lolviz and graphviz to visualize data structures, but there is no output. This is the error I get in server logs: groupn.pythonanywhere.com.server.log

```
Warning: 2017-11-14 16:32:24 Illegal attribute sides in <TD> - ignored 2017-11-14 16:32:24   
Warning: 2017-11-14 16:32:24 Illegal attribute sides in <TD> - ignored 2017-11-14 16:32:24 in label of node node140165832004944 2017-11-14 16:32:24   
Warning: 2017-11-14 16:32:24 Illegal attribute sides in <TD> - ignored 2017-11-14 16:32:24 in label of node node140165832024136 2017-11-14 16:32:24   
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/pdf" 2017-11-14 16:32:24 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: 2017-11-14 16:32:24   
 links2: not found
```

This is where the function is in my views.py

```
elif 'show' in request.POST:
                data = callviz(s).view(filename=None, directory=None, cleanup=True)
                return render(request, 'file/stacks.html', {'form': form, 'data': data})
```

Answer (score 1):

view is trying to open the generated viz as a PDF on PythonAnywhere. That's not a particularly useful thing to do in a web app. Generate the viz into some format that you can embed in to a web page or offer for download.